# Alter a MYSQL table add a primary key and then partiton the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please explain me the check points which I need to consider, when I am trying to add a Primary Key to a MYSQL table and then partition it according to a date column of that table

Answer (score 0):

For the primary key creation:

You probably want to make sure that:

- there is no primary key already defined on the table,

  Use the `DESCRIBE TABLE` query.
- the columns which will serve as the primary key don't contain duplicates when aggregated.

  ```
  SELECT CONCAT(col1, col2, col3) AS key
  FROM table
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
  HAVING COUNT(key) > 1
  ```

  Alternatively, you can use the `IGNORE` option on the `ALTER TABLE` query to drop the duplicates and keep the first matching entry as the primary key.
- Except for InnoDB, ensure that there is at least as much free space as needed on the storage node, which is usuallly a bit more than the size of the table, since MySQL will want to copy the table in a new file as it alters it.

For partitioning on a specific column, that column must be a part of the primary key, and optionally an index on its own. So you will have to include the date you wish to partition on in the column group used for the primary key creation and in the check list above.